# Border is not covering the entire area

Tags: .net, wpf, rounded-corners

I am new to WPF. My requirement is to make a splash screen with rounded rectangle. I did some searching and achieved the round rectangle. But the issue is that it fails some area. Kindly see the screenshot and check the code below.
[image]

In that image you can see the black border is breaking at the corners

Here is my xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TimeLogger.StartWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"   Width="470" Height="270"      ShowInTaskbar="False" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
        ResizeMode="NoResize"  WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent"  >
    <Border BorderBrush="#FF000000" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" CornerRadius="8,8,8,8">
        <Grid Background="#012a7a"   >
            <Label Margin="-5,-7,5,7">
                <TextBlock Foreground="Black"  FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="25" FontStretch="UltraExpanded" Height="71" Width="177">
                    TimeLogger
                </TextBlock>
            </Label>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

Comment: why did you place a textblock with in a label ?

Comment: @eranotzap . I need to show some text inside a label , I need to achieve something equivalent of "<asp:Label ID="txtBox" runat="server" `Text="MyText"` />

Comment: <Label Content="Some text" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying a corner radius to a border does not shrink the size of the border's content so that it's circumscribed. You're seeing the Grid painting on top of the border because it's still filling the full area that the border says it has available. The fix is fairly easy:

1. Set the background color on your border, not the grid. Leave the grid transparent.
2. Apply a padding to the border or a margin to the grid so that it leaves room for the applied corner radius. Play with the exact value until you get something you like.

Something like this:

```
<Border 
    BorderBrush="#FF000000" 
    Background="#012a7a" 
    BorderThickness="2" 
    CornerRadius="8"
    Padding="5"
    >
    <Grid>
        <!-- In a code review, I'd question the value of negative margin on this label -->
        <Label Margin="-5,-7,5,7">
            <TextBlock Foreground="Black"  FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="25" FontStretch="UltraExpanded" Height="71" Width="177">
                TimeLogger
            </TextBlock>
        </Label>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see your problem.

`Border`s are great things. They are lightweight and have a great amount of control over appearance.  **The issue is that you've given your `Grid` a `Background` color whereas you should have given it to your `Border`.** Typically, Grids don't make good elements to style, especially when you're already using a Border here.  The grid is great for simple to complex layouts, and occasionally it makes sense to give them a `Background` but it is almost always best for layouts only.

Just copy paste this:

```
<Border BorderBrush="#FF000000" Background="#012a7a" BorderThickness="2,2,2,2" CornerRadius="8,8,8,8">
    <Grid>
        <Label Margin="-5,-7,5,7">
            <TextBlock Foreground="Black"  FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="25" FontStretch="UltraExpanded" Height="71" Width="177">
                TimeLogger
            </TextBlock>
        </Label>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 0):

Border is a content control just but the TextBlock in it

```
<Border Background="#012a7a" BorderBrush="#FF000000" Margin ="6" BorderThickness="4" CornerRadius="8,8,8,8">
    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Margin="-5,-7,5,7" Height="71" Width="177"
               VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
               FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="25" FontStretch="UltraExpanded" 
               Text="TimeLogger" />
</Border>
```